# No viewDidLoad method in PSListController

Tags: ios, jailbreak, viewdidload, theos, private-methods

I have checked recent header files for `PSListController` , `PSViewController` and `PSBaseView`, but there is no method for acknowledgement of view creation, like iOS has `viewDidLoad` - Although there are many methods available for view Display. One I found is: `-(id)initForContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize`, but I don't want to use it as I don't think it would be appropriate to do so.

So which method should I choose in order to initialize my instance variables or do other stuff? Thanks.

**Note:** I am using [rpetrich's Header Files](https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders).

Comment: Please provide a link to the actual header files; there are too many folders in the link provided to find the correct headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those headers are slightly older on the repository but looking at an iOS 7 version of PSViewController you will see that it is a subclass of UIViewController. UIViewController does contain viewDidLoad so PSListViewController "should"  contain the same.

Source: http://www.developer.limneos.net/?framework=Preferences.framework&header=PSViewController.h

Comment: Thanks for the link. You are right. I have got some old headers.